# Calculating Eulers number using BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, eulers-number

I am trying to make a program to approximate e by summing the following number series:

e = 1 + (1 / 1!) + (1 / 2!) + (1 / 3!) .... + (1 / i!)

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);
        BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal(1.0);
        BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(1.0);

        for (int i =  1; i <= 12; i++) {

            divisor = divisor.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
            e = e.add(one.divide(divisor));

            System.out.println("e = " + e);

        }
    }
```

The program performs the calculation (1 / n!) succesfully for n <= 2, but as soon as n >= 3 I get an error message. It seems like the program can't handle a divisor bigger than 2. The output of the program is:

e = 2

e = 2.5

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(Unknown Source)  at ch10.Chapter_10_E20_ApproximateE.main(Chapter_10_E20_ApproximateE.java:16)*

How should I use the BigDecimal class to preform a summation for e = 1 + (1 / 1!) + (1 / 2!) + (1 / 3!) .... + (1 / i!) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we all know, dividing by `3` yields a number with a decimal representation that continues forever.

```
0.5 / 3 = 0.166666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666....
```

That is like what is going on with your division internally in the `BigDecimal`, except that `int`s in binary form are being calculated.

You will need a [different overload of `divide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) that takes a scale to use (number of decimal digits beyond the decimal point) and the rounding mode.  This tells the `BigDecimal` how many digits to use and how to round when it stops.

```
e = e.add(one.divide(divisor, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

Final estimate of `e` outputted:

```
e = 2.71828182828616856395
```

Comment: Actually, divide usually takes a precision (total number of represented digits).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that BigDecimal is trying to compute the value exactly and it cannot do that because 1/3 repeats forever in base 10.

To fix this you need to define a precision and a rounding mode. For example:

```
  e = e.add( one.divide(divisor, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP) );
```